# SQL Enterprise Partitioned is slower than Standard

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I have been bench-marking SQL Server Enterprise and Standard, Enterprise is using Partitioning by month on the table. The table only has 3 fields, Date-time (DateTimeOffeset(3)), Value (integer in the tests) Quality (always set to 192).

The Testing computer,I7 3770, Win8, 16G Ram, 1 TB Harddrive 5400 RPM. Each SQL server was tested in a VM with 4 GIGs of ram, 4 CPU Cores, 40GB HD space and on windows server 2008. The only difference in the VM's was SQL Server Standard vs Enterprise.

The dataset in the table is a sample every 5 seconds. First test was to load a years worth of data, (starting from today - 1 year), then select 1 day worth of data from 1 Month ago. In this test Sql server Enterprise was indeed faster.

The second test was to load 5 years of data, starting 5 years from today, then query the same data as in the last test. SQL server standard is way faster at this. My thought was that with partioning Enterprise should be faster. The table ID is the DATETIME field and is what is being used in the WHERE Clause.

Any ideas what I have done wrong? Is this normal? I have read many forums but haven't found any that try to compare Standard VS Enterprise.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: So you did partition? Partitioning makes most queries slower, some faster. It is not a magic go faster switch. It is mostly used to quickly drop data in bulk.